# Android Does not Stop Music on call and Dont Resume on app icon click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I am new to android developemt. I made a music player with 3 buttons play,pause,stop. When i click on app icon Splash will run and after 3 sec it go out and when i click on play it pays the song other buttons works perfectly. But if i play the music and back to homescreen music will play but if i click on the app icon again it will start a new instance of it and if click over the play button it will start another song means 2 songs are running now.

Another problem is my songs resumes when i got the call and when i pick the call it still palying how to solve these issues.

My code for playing the music is

```
MediaPlayer mySong;
    Button playButton,pauseButton,stopButton,creditsButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        playButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        pauseButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        stopButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        creditsButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.credit);
        mySong=MediaPlayer.create(StartingPoint.this, R.raw.song);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mySong.start();
            };
        });

pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mySong.pause();
            };
        });
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mySong.pause();
        mySong.seekTo(0);
    };
});
```

My manifest file is

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="com.simplyitsols.hanumanchalisa.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.simplyitsols.hanumanchalisa.StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.simplyitsols.hanumanchalisa.STARTINGPOINT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.simplyitsols.hanumanchalisa.Credits"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: you need to back to home screen and incoming call stop the music?

Comment: In both the condition music runs.... 1. If my app is on top or running or its running in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a service: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

After you have achieved that, you have to implement onPause and onResume of your activity in order to do what you want.
onPause is triggered when you go back to home or you receive an incoming call. OnResume is self explanatory :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Comment: But tell if we let the music aside than i have one more problem that if my app is running and songs is playing. Now i click on back and back to home screen. Now when i click on the app icon again it starts a fresh application not the background app where as i am using the mode as singleTask

Comment: try with singleInstance (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Before you hit back, clear the stack by calling finish() and kill your current activity. And for the new instance getting generated, put a boolean check whether song is currently being played or not.

```
   if( isSongPlaying==true)
     {
        //do not start  
      }
   else
     {
      //start playing
      }
```

Comment: If i finishs the activity it will not work in background. And music will stop

Answer (score 0):

According to this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

you need to put this code in the activity's class:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
...
}
```